# Visual Studio collapsing html code

Tags: c#, html, visual-studio-2013

i have some html code as follows, which was supplied by our graphics developers. the issue is when i import this into asp.net (c#) page i get to see a lot of orphan divs. it feels as if there are not opening divs for several of the closing divs. following is code snippet.

```
<div class="col-lg-2 col-lg-3 quick-launch">
    <div class="thumbnail">
        <a href=""> <img src="assets/img/app_images/app_7.jpg" width="115" height="114">
        <div class="caption">
            <h3>TEST</h3>
        </a></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

could someone here please let me know if there is something in visual studio that is causing this?

Comment: I don't see the issue, you have three opening `<div>` elements and three closing `</div>` elements in the code you provided.

Comment: @jzworkman I think he's trying to say this isn't the case when he imports it--that visual studio is somehow removing some of the closing divs. Although I don't know why it would.

Comment: Right visual studio shouldn't be doing anything with the files on import, it should take the file as is.  Does it show any errors? Or does it just show the `<div>` as collapsed?

Comment: The markup is invalid; the anchor has a div starting within it but ending outside of it

Comment: @Carl it's not invalid (for HTML code, of course it's invalid XHTML) but it confuses vs editor.

Answer (score 1):

You're inverting `<div>` and `<a>` closing tags. This is valid HTML (but not valid XHTML so you'd better to check your `DOCTYPE`) but it may *confuse* Visual Studio editor:

```
<a href=""> <img src="assets/img/app_images/app_7.jpg" width="115" height="114">
    <div class="caption">
    <h3>TEST</h3>
    </a>
</div>
```

a 
Should be:

```
<a href=""> <img src="assets/img/app_images/app_7.jpg" width="115" height="114">
    <div class="caption">
        <h3>TEST</h3>
    </div>
</a>
```

**Edit:** what's wrong with that? It works because HTML parser doesn't *complain* about `<a><div><a/></div>` (if `DOCTYPE` isnt `XHTML`) but **you** should complain about it. Let me explain: parser won't complain because `</div>` (closing tag) isn't optional then it won't just silently add it. This is theory, in practice browsers handle this in many ways. Some of them silently close `<div>` when `</a>` is reached (then `</div>` will close outer one), some others don't do it (I repeat because it's not an optional closing tag) then `</div>` will close inner (and right) one. IMO With such unreliable behavior you should ask your developer/graphics designer to fix that code. In general (and with few exceptions like `<hr>` and `<br>`) I would write HTML code *as it was* XHTML.

Comment: yes, i can see that the div tag is inside the anchor tag but it seems to work when rendered. if i were to use this use what should i change the doctype to be?

Comment: @user1144596 it works because HTML parser doesn't _complain_ about `<a><b><a/></b>` (if `DOCTYPE` isnt `XHTML`) but **you** should complain about it. Let me explain: parser won't complain (because a missing tag, even when not optional, is not confusing in this case. `</div>` (closing tag) isn't optional then it'll just add it. When you finally have `</div>` you're in limbo: parser and renderer may be smart enough to understand you inverted them (again because `</div>` is not optional) or it may _think_ you're closing the outer one.

Comment: You can't depend on case (what about browsers? how different versions will behave?). If you're targeting HTML 5 (`DOCTYPE HTML`) I'd write everything _as it was_ XHTML with few exceptions (for example `<hr>` and `<br>`) so in your case I'd ask developer/designer to fix it. Of course this is just my very personal opinion!

Comment: ok, all that makes sense. fixing it might mean recoding a whole lot...so let's see how that goes?

Comment: @user1144596 you may _try_ but you may also fix it with a simple program, read in sequence each node (with a HTML parser, not XML) and revert them when you have this situation (just keep track of last "a" node pushed in your queue). Anyway afterl all it may not even be a problem...